# How to use remember_token in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I use `Auth::attempt($credentials, true)` so that Laravel generates the token.

What I want to do is when the user is logged in, I want to return this token and store it in a client-side storage and use that token to match the one which is in the database, and return the user details.

Is it the correct way to remember the users?

Answer (score 0):

yes correct way but better to  used laravel [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport) package for this type of functionality do (return this token and store it in a client-side storage and use that token to match the one which is in the database, and return the user details)

store token by client side  to in `cookie` otherwise used `localstorage`

Comment: I am waiting for the other answers too! I will mark this as the answer if none of others reply!